# Dynamically load partials in single Ractive instance

Tags: ractivejs

I would like to make a template that can determine which partial it will render, such that

In Template:

```
{{#objectA}}
  {{>partial}}
{{/}}
{{objectB}}
  {{>partial}}
{{/}}
```

Where partial is a property with template value on objectA and objectB

Is there any reasonable way of doing this, or something similar in a single instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [Partial Expressions aka dynamic partials](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/partials#expressions) they do exactly that based on resolution of the partial name as a reference. Assuming each object had a `foo` property:

```
{{#partial bar}}
 bar partial!
{{/partial}}

{{#partial qux}}
 qux partial!
{{/partial}}

{{#each items}}
    <li>item {{>foo}}
{{/each}}
```

And data was like:

```
items: [
    { foo: 'bar' },
    { foo: 'qux' },     
]
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/52k645wh/